# Mclust (R) equivalent package in Python

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, machine-learning

Is there an `Mclust` equivalent command in Python? I searched the documentation for `sklearn`. It has GMM for classification, not for clustering.

I have installed `rpy2`, but I am not sure how to install the `Mclust` package in R to Python.

Comment: From looking at the docs, it appears GMM is unsupervised. In which case it will create a set of n_comp classes without being given labels. Is this any different from "GMM for clustering"?

Comment: In fact GMM is unsupervised but by running the fit method followed by the predict method you will get the labels (as numbers) of each cluster.

Answer (score 1):

`scilearn-kit` has a lot of machine learning goodies all packed into one package. You get tools for regression, classification and clustering too. I don't know if it covers all of the `mclust` utilities but it should come pretty close . Have a look at what it has to offer here : http://scikit-learn.org

Comment: Thanks. sklearn (or scilearn-kit) does not have model-based mixture of gaussian clustering.

Answer (score 0):

R has a system to fetch and install packages (*one* system... at the difference of Python).

It can be used directly from R, obviously, but rpy2 offers a way to use it without leaving Python:
http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/robjects_rpackages.html